# Browsers file upload percentage event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, file-upload

I am having a small asp.net application where user uploads file to a FTP server via FTPWebRequest. All the internet examples for upload progress bar goes with ajax. But mine is programmed differently with a File Upload handler from asp.net.

Even when there is no upload progress bar functions either on the client or server side which I have written, the chrome browser manages to show the upload percentage on the left bottom of the window.

[image: chrome upload progress bar]

Can someone explain this behavior and is there a way to catch this percentage event via javascript/jquery ?